# How to allow more than two words to be checked in this Java Code

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, languagetool

I need to modify this script so that more than two words can be checked and my knowledge of Java is too limited to make the changes myself.
This script is part of an opensource grammar checker for OpenOffice (LanguageTool), and the scripts purpose is to replace certain words with other words.

The file of words to be checked is called "coherency.txt" and it's format is like this:
WrongWord1=CorrectWord1
WrongWord2=CorrectWord2

And when I type: WrongWord1 it is flagged by the script and tells me I should use CorrectWord1 instead.

But I need to be able to have three words or more, like this:
WrongWord1=WrongWord2=CorrectWord1
WrongWord3=WrongWord4=WrongWord5=CorrectWord2
WrongWord6=CorrectWord3

So that when I type WrongWord3 it is flagged and the script tells me I should use CorrectWord2
OR
when I type WrongWord2 it also is flagged and the script tells me I should use CorrectWord1

If you can help I can put a link to your webpage at http://www.sbbic.org/lang/en-us/volunteer/

Any help you can give on how to modify this code to allow more than two words to be compared a replaced would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Nathan

```
    /* LanguageTool, a natural language style checker 
 * Copyright (C) 2005 Daniel Naber (http://www.danielnaber.de)
 * 
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301
 * USA
 */
package de.danielnaber.languagetool.rules;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import de.danielnaber.languagetool.AnalyzedSentence;
import de.danielnaber.languagetool.AnalyzedTokenReadings;
import de.danielnaber.languagetool.JLanguageTool;
import de.danielnaber.languagetool.tools.StringTools;

/**
 * A Khmer rule that matches words or phrases which should not be used and suggests
 * correct ones instead. Loads the relevant words  from 
 * <code>rules/km/coherency.txt</code>, where km is a code of the language.
 * 
 * @author Andriy Rysin
 */
public abstract class KhmerWordCoherencyRule extends KhmerRule {

  private Map<String, String> wrongWords; // e.g. "вреѿті реѿт" -> "зреѿтою"

  private static final String FILE_NAME = "/km/coherency.txt";

  public abstract String getFileName();

  private static final String FILE_ENCODING = "utf-8";

  public String getEncoding() {
    return FILE_ENCODING;
  }

  /**
   * Indicates if the rule is case-sensitive. Default value is <code>true</code>.
   * @return true if the rule is case-sensitive, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isCaseSensitive() {
    return false;  
  }

  /**
   * @return the locale used for case conversion when {@link #isCaseSensitive()} is set to <code>false</code>.
   */
  public Locale getLocale() {
    return Locale.getDefault();
  }  

  public KhmerWordCoherencyRule(final ResourceBundle messages) throws IOException {
    if (messages != null) {
      super.setCategory(new Category(messages.getString("category_misc")));
    }
    wrongWords = loadWords(JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().getFromRulesDirAsStream(getFileName()));
  }

  public String getId() {
    return "KM_WORD_COHERENCY";
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return "Checks for wrong words/phrases";
  }

  public String getSuggestion() {
    return " is not valid, use ";
  }

  public String getShort() {
    return "Wrong word";
  }

  public final RuleMatch[] match(final AnalyzedSentence text) {
    final List<RuleMatch> ruleMatches = new ArrayList<RuleMatch>();
    final AnalyzedTokenReadings[] tokens = text.getTokensWithoutWhitespace();

    for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {
      final String token = tokens[i].getToken();

      final String origToken = token;
      final String replacement = isCaseSensitive()?wrongWords.get(token):wrongWords.get(token.toLowerCase(getLocale()));
      if (replacement != null) {
        final String msg = token + getSuggestion() + replacement;
        final int pos = tokens[i].getStartPos();
        final RuleMatch potentialRuleMatch = new RuleMatch(this, pos, pos
            + origToken.length(), msg, getShort());
        if (!isCaseSensitive() && StringTools.startsWithUppercase(token)) {
          potentialRuleMatch.setSuggestedReplacement(StringTools.uppercaseFirstChar(replacement));
        } else {
          potentialRuleMatch.setSuggestedReplacement(replacement);
        }
        ruleMatches.add(potentialRuleMatch);
      }
    }
    return toRuleMatchArray(ruleMatches);
  }


  private Map<String, String> loadWords(final InputStream file) throws IOException {
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
      isr = new InputStreamReader(file, getEncoding());
      br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String line;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (line.length() < 1) {
          continue;
        }
        if (line.charAt(0) == '#') { // ignore comments
          continue;
        }
        final String[] parts = line.split("=");
        if (parts.length != 2) {
          throw new IOException("Format error in file "
              + JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().getFromRulesDirAsUrl(getFileName()) + ", line: " + line);
        }
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
      }

    } finally {
      if (br != null) {
        br.close();
      }
      if (isr != null) {
        isr.close();
      }
    }
    return map;
  }

  public void reset() {
  }  

}
```

Comment: You posted way too much code. Post the smallest piece of code that demonstrates your problem. I'm not even sure what your problem is.

Comment: if someone does what you ask, do you have the expertise to compile the adjusted source code and, if needed, package all compiled sources in a JAR file again? Because it's not likely to simply "work" by replacing the adjusted source.

Comment: Are you sure that it is like *word1=wrongword2* and not *wrongword2=word1*?

Comment: Thanks guys, yes you are right, I had the order messed up - it is Wrongword1=CorrectWord1.  @Bart Yes, I can compile the source, it took me awhile, like I said I don't know Java, but I can compile the source and get it to work in OpenOffice.  @Falmarri Sorry, I posted the whole thing because that is the issue, I don't know what needs to be changed either - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small adaptations:

Consider changing the desired input format to

```
WrongWord = CorrectWord[, CorrectWord]*
```

The key will be the incorrect word, the value a comma separated list of correct alternatives. So you can keep the file parsing as it is.

The Map should be of type `Map<String, Set<String>>` - each token maps to a set of alternatives.

Now you can split each line around `=` to get a key/value pair and each value around `,` to get an array of suggested tokens to replace the input.

---

Then you'll need some changes in th `match` to assemble new message, because you expect more then one suggestions now.

Change the lines after `final String origToken = token;` to

```
final String[] replacements = wrongWords.get(token);
  if (replacements != null) {
    final String msg = createMessage(token, replacements);
    final int pos = tokens[i].getStartPos();
```

and implement the `createMessage` method to return a human readable message that tells the user the one to many alternatives for the token.

Comment: You are right Andreas - I changed the question to match reality.  Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand you right that in the coherency.txt file I should put Word = WrongWord[, WrongWord]* ?
Let me do a real word example to make sure I understand: Hello = Hi[Hullo, Hiya]*
Or should it be Hello = Hi[Hullo, Hi]* (with "Hi repeated two times)? Thanks for being willing to help me.

Comment: @Nathan - I chose a quite common syntax, a real line to match this "pattern" could be `Wrong1 = Correct1` as well as `Wrong2 = Correct2a, Correct2b`.

Comment: Also when I try to compile the code I get an error for the code: Map<String, Set<String>>

Comment: @Nathan - Changing the map signature requires more than one changes in your code. Please show line and error message.

Comment: I had failed to call the Set interface (import java.util.Set;), I am testing the code now (sorry, I've never done Java, thanks for your patience!).

Comment: Ok, I did my best to try out your modification.  I couldn't get the "createMessage" method to work, I think because this script is part of a larger script.  So I changed the Map to :Map<Set<String>, String> (so that there would only be one suggestion - is that right?) and I get this error: KhmerWordCoherencyRule.java:154: put(java.util.Se
t<java.lang.String>,java.lang.String) in java.util.Map<java.util.Set<java.lang.S
tring>,java.lang.String> cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String
)
    [javac]         map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    [javac]            ^

Comment: @Nathan - unfortunatly I really doubt, that you'll be able to modify that java code - you'll definitly need Java programming skills. The signature change is not correct. It *has* to be `Map<String, Set<String>>` - the key (`String`) is a token candidate, the value (`Set<String>`) a `Set` that contains suggested alternatives. Don't change the order, otherwise the map won't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Andreas - I will keep trying - part of the issue is that having Wrong2 = Correct2a, Correct2b isn't what I need, I need it to be Wrong1, Wrong2 = Correct1 - which like you said, probably isn't just a minor tweak of the code which someone who doesn't know Java can do.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you have to change is this part in loadWords:

```
final String[] parts = line.split("=");
if (parts.length != 2) {
    throw new IOException("Format error in file " + JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().getFromRulesDirAsUrl(getFileName()) + ", line: " + line);
}
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

This one puts the left hand side of the equals as key and the right hand side as value into the map. Therefore I think the left hand side has to be the wrong word. Therefore your input should become *wrong1 = wrong2 = ... = correct*.

With this setting you could simply change it to the following

```
final String[] parts = line.split("=");
if (parts.length < 2) {
    throw new IOException("Format error in file " + JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().getFromRulesDirAsUrl(getFileName()) + ", line: " + line);
}
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
    map.put(parts[i], parts[parts.length - 1]);
}
```

which would produce the folowing entries in the map:

```
wrong1 = correct
wrong2 = correct
wrong3 = correct
...
```

Probably it is not the most efficient solution, but it should work somehow like this. With this map wrong words can be searched and the suggestions will be the correct ones.

(P.S.: I could not run the code, so there could be some coding errors in it)

Comment: Thanks Hons, I tried this solution and while it didn't cause any errors (by having a parts length of more than two), the code didn't flag the incorrect words...the reason the code can't be run is because it is calling other scripts which are included in the source of LanguageTool, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this farther...is there anything I can give you that would be helpful to find a solution that works?  Thanks for spending the time to take a look at this for me.

Comment: Of course, there have to be at least two parts... In your version it checked to have exactly two and in my version it has to have at least two. It's not clear to me what do you mean by "flag incorrect words". If you exchange the lines mentioned above with the ones I wrote and you feed it with your original file it should do exactly the same as before. At the end it just returns an Array of RuleMatch

Comment: Thanks Hons, what I mean by "flag incorrect words" is when compile the code and then use this extension (the java code is part of an extension) in OpenOffice, the extension no longer flags the words for replacement (when I write wrongword1 it doesn't tell me to use correctword1).  I tried using my previous coherency.txt file with only two words, and it also does not flag any words as incorrect...not sure how to troubleshoot it though...any thoughts?

Comment: Probably you have to register your new Language extension to the tool. Have done all the stuff to add a new language like described here? http://www.languagetool.org/development/#newlanguage

Comment: Yes, I have the new language working fine - I am just trying to modify a java rule (as here: http://www.languagetool.org/development/#javarules)

Comment: I suppose that you have added the ID to the file specified in the documantation, so lets go a step back. Did the class KhmerWordCoherencyRule that you posted at the beginning of this thread work?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine, and I called it in Khmer.java (which is in the java source under languages - called it as "KM_WORD_COHERENCY"

Comment: Hey, thanks for working with me on this Hons, but I think Andreas is right - this is out of my league - I'm going to ask help directly from the writers of the program (they said they could help, but it would just take a while).  Once I get 15 points, I will give you a good rating.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;




public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String txtFromFile = "Hipopotamus=hIppoPotamus=hiiippotamus Magazine=Mazagine=Masagine";
            String searchWord = "Masagine";
            Pattern searchPattern= Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\w+=)*?("+searchWord+")");
            Matcher m = searchPattern.matcher(txtFromFile);
            String source = "";
            while(m.find()) {
                source = m.group();
                System.out.println("word pairs:"+source);
            }
            System.out.println("correct word:"+source.split("=")[0]);
        }
    }
```